# Drupal 8: programmatically create node and redirect to it using form api

Tags: drupal-8

How do you programmatically add a node from a custom form (forms api) and then redirect to that node after saving it?

Figured out the below answer after looking for half a day.

Hope this is useful to someone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'type' is the node machine name

'title' is the title you want to give the new node

you can add more 'field_names' that are used in your node

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $newCompanyNode = Node::create([
      'type' => 'company',
      'title' => $form_state->getValue('company'),
      //'field_name' => $value,
    ]);

    $newCompanyNode->save();
    drupal_set_message('Your company has been registered.', 'status');
    $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $newCompanyNode->id()]);
    return $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);

  }
```

For more info on how to setup a custom form:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api